# Equivalent quadratic forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, quadratic-forms

Two quadratic forms $$Q(x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n) \\ \text{ and } Q'(x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n)$$ are called equivalent $$\Leftrightarrow Q'(x)=Q(Tx), \text{ where } T \in M_n(K), \text{ invertible }$$

When we have $$Q(x, y)=x^2+y^2 \\\ Q'(x, y)=5x^2+5y^2$$ how can we check if they are equivalent??? How can we find such a $T$ ???

Comment: http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/58629280.jpg

Comment: Do you know the notion of equivalent matrices?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No. Which is the notion of equivalent matrices?

Comment: I am just wondering have you been taught how to find $T$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal That is what I don't understand. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the base field $K$, this might be a difficult problem in general.

However, for quadratic forms of rank $2$, this is easy. You just have to check that the two quadratic forms have same discriminant, and represents a commun value, for example, which is the case here $5$ is represented by both quadratic forms, and the two determinants are equal to $1$ mod squares.

In your particular case, it is better to notice that $5=1^2+2^2$, and write $(1^2+2^2)(x^2+y^2)=(x-2y)^2+(2x+y)^2$, which provides you everything you want, since the linear forms $x+2y$ and $2x+y$ are independent.

Comment: So two quadratic forms of rank $2$ are equivalent if the two quadratic forms have the same discriminant? What do you mean with " represents a commun value" ?

Comment: no: two quadratic forms are equivalent if they have same discriminant AND represents a nonzero common value (i forgot nonzero), (meaning that there exists $a\in K^\times$ and two vectors $v,v'$ such that $Q(v)=Q(v')=a)$.

Comment: How can we calculate the discriminant of a quadratic form of rank $2$ ?

Comment: And how do we find the matrix $T$ ??? I haven't understood it...

Comment: Well, you should read a textbook on quadratic forms first. Moreover, if you really have understood the definition of equivalence of quadratic forms, you should be able to find $T$ from the equality $x^2+y^2=(x-2y)^2+(2x+y)^2$.

Comment: When $x^2+y^2=(x-2y)^2+(2x+y^2)$, then $$T= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 \\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$ or not? 
How do we know that we have to write it in the form $$x^2+y^2=(x-2y)^2+(2x+y)^2$$ ???